# Need help sorting a list with letters and numbers in each entry

Tags: python

In my code I need to ask the user to input items of a shopping list and then sort that list into descending order by price.

For example if the user where to enter

> : Butter 1.70, Coffee 4.99, Milk 0.45,
> Kitchen Towel 1.75, Washing powder 6.20

The output should be:

> Washing powder 6.20, Coffee 4.99, Kitchen Towel
> 1.75, Butter 1.70, Milk 0.45

However I am completely stuck on how to actually do this. Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe break the problem down into small bits. You could start by parsing the string into item--value tuple pairs, then worry about sorting it once you've done that.

Comment: "Completely stuck" can mean anything. Show what you did and what did not work, explain why you expected that to work and what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not so robust but it works.

```
import re
value = lambda x: list(map(float,re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)))

s = "Butter 1.70, Coffee 4.99, Milk 0.45, Kitchen Towel 1.75, Washing powder 6.20"
items = s.split(',')
items.sort(key=value, reverse=True)
print(', '.join(items))
```

> Washing powder 6.20,  Coffee 4.99,  Kitchen Towel 1.75, Butter 1.70,  Milk 0.45

Comment: You are right! i've corrected the response, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's some high level steps I'd start with, lmk if you need help with any particular step.

1. split up list with something like `input.split(',').strip()`
2. For each element, split by space `item.split(' ')`
3. Assume the number is the last 'word' of each element. Convert that word to a number.
4. Do the sort.